# How do return the value of an attribute in a nested object without using the traditional js object navigation style?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, search

For example how do I automatically loop through all "value" attributes in the object below without doing "tags.value" or "style.value"

```
[
  {
    "title": "Old Man's War",
    "author": {
      "name": "John Scalzi",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "American"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "The Lock Artist",
    "author": {
      "name": "Steve Hamilton",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "English"
        }
      "style": [
        {
          "value": "Italix"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking to extract a list of all styles & tags? One direct way is through a `reduce()`, `map()` combo

```
let attributes = data.reduce((b, a) => ({
    tags: [...b.tags, a.author.tags?.map(v => v.value) || []].flat(),
    styles: [...b.styles, a.author.style?.map(v => v.value) || []].flat() }), {tags:[], styles:[]})
```

Output:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "American",
    "English"
  ],
  "styles": [
    "Italix"
  ]
}
```

```js
const data = [{
  "title": "Old Man's War",
  "author": {
    "name": "John Scalzi",
    "tags": [{
      "value": "American"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "title": "The Lock Artist",
  "author": {
    "name": "Steve Hamilton",
    "tags": [{
      "value": "English"
    }],
    "style": [{
      "value": "Italix"
    }]
  }
}]

// just the tag values

let attributes = data.reduce((b, a) => ({
    tags: [...b.tags, a.author.tags?.map(v => v.value) || []].flat(),
    styles: [...b.styles, a.author.style?.map(v => v.value) || []].flat() }), {tags:[], styles:[]})
console.log(attributes)
```

Comment: @user16192387 - did this help you solve your issue? If so, pls mark as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```js
//first,there is an error in your json.I assume it like this
const data = [
   {
      "title":"Old Man's War",
      "author":{
         "name":"John Scalzi",
         "tags":[
            {
               "value":"American"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "title":"The Lock Artist",
      "author":{
         "name":"Steve Hamilton",
         "tags":[
            {
               "value":"English"
            }
         ],
         "style":[
            {
               "value":"Italix"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]

for(const top of data){
  if(typeof top == 'object'){
    for(const second_key in top){
      const second = top[second_key]
      if(typeof second == 'object'){
        for(const third_key in second){
          const third = second[third_key]
          if(Array.isArray(third)){
            for(const fourth of third){
              document.write(fourth['value']+"<br>")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
//this is another solution
const data = [
   {
      "title":"Old Man's War",
      "author":{
         "name":"John Scalzi",
         "tags":[
            {
               "value":"American"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "title":"The Lock Artist",
      "author":{
         "name":"Steve Hamilton",
         "tags":[
            {
               "value":"English"
            }
         ],
         "style":[
            {
               "value":"Italix"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]

function lookForValue(obj){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty('value')){
    document.write(obj['value']+"<br>")
    return
  }
  if(typeof obj == 'object'){
    for(const key in obj){
      lookForValue(obj[key])
    }
  }
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    for(const item in obj){
      lookForValue(item)
    }
  }
}

lookForValue(data)
```